# Unable to retrieve data from POST request

Tags: java

I am working in JAVA 1.8 to write and using Apache Tomcat to run the server, I am unable to retrieve data from a POST request i.e in JSON.

I actually need it in an HashMap and I can even parse and convert it into HashMap even if it is readable in JSON. I have tried several links on the internet and I always get exception like `Could not deserialize to type interface PACKAGE NAME.`

```
   @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("ClassifyCase")
    public Rules Classify(HttpServletRequest request) {

        StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
          String line = null;
          try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
              jb.append(line);
          } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Buffer Reader Error"); }

          System.out.println("What I read: "+jb);
        System.out.println("Here la la l ala ");
//      System.out.println("Case: ++ "+Case.toString());
        System.out.println("Here la la l ala ");
        Rules foundRule = new Rules();
//        List<Rules> objListRules = new  ArrayList<Rules>();
        try
        {
            DataAccessInterface objDAInterface = new RuleDataAdapter();
            AbstractDataBridge objADBridge = new DatabaseStorage(objDAInterface);
//          foundRule = objADBridge.Classify(Case);
            logger.info("Classification done!");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.info("Error in classification");
            System.out.println("Couldnt Classify Properly!");
//          return 
        }
        return foundRule;
}
```

[image: This is how I am sending data through postman in JSON]

Can someone please share a guide on how can I receive this data and convert it into a Map or either I can directly get a Map!

Comment: Use GSON and write a custom deserialiser. GSON cannot deserialise to interfaces, so you'll have to write a custom deserialiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to use this library of JSON..

[image: You can find it in Maven Repository]

You can find it in **Maven Repository** and it's so easy to parse a `JSON` to a `Map` or to a `JSONArray` or `JSONObject`... depends of your necessity what you want to do..

Here is a example show how to parse a `JSON` to a `HashMap`

```
Map<String, Object> map = new JSONObject(--JSONString here--).toMap();
```

And that's all...

Now, if your `JSON` has a list of objects, i mean like a list of `maps`, what you just need to do is this...

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(--JSON string here--);

 for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
   Map<String, Object> map = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toMap();
 }
```

**Here is the explanation.**

You take you `JSON` string and pass it as a parameter to the `JSONArray`,*what `JSONArray does is, take your json string a parse it to like a list`*

Then you make a `for` to get each `Object` of that list and parse it to a `map`.

**Note**: what the `JSONObject` does, is take the object of the `JSONArray` and parse it... you can parse it to a map or you can get each object of that map..

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I am confused, please respond to these questions, I will be thankful: 1) Am I sending it through postman correctly? 2) What I need to change here ```public Rules Classify(HttpServletRequest request) {``` 3) Where I need to use your code in above answer

Comment: Hi @MalikAtifAziz, 1) Yes, you are sending it through postman correcty,   2) this question is respond in the third question,  3) I give you this code to avoid all that code you have there... that's too much code (for me) just to get a simple request.

The code that i post here is to replace yours with mine I just gave you... as you can see.. the code I have just given you is easy to read and understand...

ALSO I recomend you to use HttpCliente library to get the JSON response... it's so easy

Answer (score 1):

```
String jsonString = "{\n" +
    "\t\"1\": \"1\",\n" +
    "\t\"FPG\": \"50\",\n" +
    "\t\"Symptoms\": \"Yes\"\n" +
    "}";
Map<String, String> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Map.class);
for (String key: map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(map.get(key));
}
```

Comment: I get you, but how to receieve JSON object in my service? What to write where I am currently writing  ````HttpServletRequset```

Comment: Map<String, String> map = new Gson().fromJson(jb.toString());

Comment: Sorry but I am confused, please respond to these questions, I will be thankful:
1) Am I sending it through postman correctly?
2) What I need to change here ```public Rules Classify(HttpServletRequest request) {```
3) Where I need to use your code in above answer

Answer (score 0):

The request you send does not contain proper JSON in the body. You are missing the commas ",". It should be something like this:

```
{
  "1":"1",
  "FPG":"50",
  "Symptoms":"yes"
}
```

Just change it and give proper JSON format to the message.
Even if the request was not in your control, I would strongly suggest that you contacted the service that creates the message and asked from them to fix it.
It would be the last resort for me to make my own deserializer to handle an "inproper" message.

An easy way to check if your JSON is properly formated is an online formatter, e.g. https://jsonformatter.org/